# graphicsView scale ignoring in drawbackground

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I just drawn grid lines in the QGraphicsView on its background

```
  drawbackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
    {
    QVarLengthArray<QLineF, 100> linesX;
    for (qreal x = left; x < sceneRect.right(); x += gridInterval )
    {

    linesX.append(QLineF(x, sceneRect.top(), x, sceneRect.bottom()));
    }

    QVarLengthArray<QLineF, 100> linesY;
    for (qreal y = top; y < sceneRect.bottom(); y += gridInterval ){

    linesY.append(QLineF(sceneRect.left(), y, sceneRect.right(), y));
    }

    painter->drawLines(linesX.data(), linesX.size());
    painter->drawLines(linesY.data(), linesY.size());
    }
```

and im scaling the view by

```
void
ViewPort::zoomIn()
{
    zoom(qreal(1.2));
}

void
ViewPort::zoomOut()
{
    zoom(1 / qreal(1.2));
}

void
ViewPort::zoom(qreal scaleFactor)
{

    qreal factor = transform().scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor).mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)).width();

    if (factor < 1 || factor > 100)
        return;

    scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

}
```

now the scen has plenty of items  that i have to scale but i need to ignore the grid lines i have drawn on the graphicsView drawBackground .
how i can ignore the scale transformation of gridLines.?

i tried QPainter::resetTransform() but in vain ..

Comment: Out of curisoity, why do not want to have gridlines scale with the view's scale (zoom) - surely the whole point of the grid is to indicate scale?

Comment: im just trying to scale or enlarge only the objects in the scene, like circle targets, polygon targets and other pixmap targets . so in the view the grid lines is more like graph plot with axis marks.

Comment: i have to update the scale value in the marks as per the scene transformed . ex: default scale will be x: 1000, y:1000 as per sceneRect. if i scaled scene to 1500, 1000, then i have to update axis to x:1500, y:1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aggregate the lines into an object which you derive from QGraphicsItem and add the item to the scene, you can then set the flag QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations, to stop it responding to scaling and other transformations.